# Crystal reports and subreports speed

Tags: crystal-reports

I created a report in Crystal Report. It has two subreports.

```
GROUP Customer

   GROUP FAMILY

   DETAIL ITEM
   The detail is for Items. This detail is inside a group. It has totals.

   FOOTER A GROUP FAMILY
    totals Item detail 

   FOOTER B GROUP FAMILY
      Subreport 1 Totals by adj (it display the detail of a third table and the totals)


FOOTER Customer

Subreport 2.
```

Totals by item. (it display the details and the totals)

The report is 48298 records. 
The tables have indexes.

Why it takes 30 minutes to run the report? Is this time "normal"?

How can I display in a footer the detail of other table?. 
Can I set a field in the footer that calls a Store Procedure and returns all values like a detail?

Comment: Where are the subreports? How many records are in the main report? How many records are in each of the subreports? What are the linking criteria? What data sources does each report / subreport query? etc. etc.

Comment: I would be surprised if 48K records took 30 min to load.

Comment: There are many possible reasons for this. Most often it is bad linking or multiple datasources that will slow down a report.

Comment: What criteria you are using in `Record Selection` formula, If your record selection is empty try to provide some filterings there so that the record are filtered and re quired are added and again check the links to subreport and main report this can play a significant role in the report buffering

Answer (score 0):

Each of the subreports will be executed for each customer. I am surprised that you are not running out of memory. My guess is that the number of customers / families is relative small (less than 300). The report is slow because it queries the database twice for each customer. Try to prepare the data inside the main report.